# vsftpd change owner permissions once uploaded

Tags: permissions, vsftpd

I am trying to setup an environment where one would upload, and once created would loose deletion and write permissions.

To do so I create a virtual user with the following settings:

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES

# Default Permissions: File: 400 ; Dir: 500
local_umask=0277
file_open_mode=0677
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

# Disable chmod
chmod_enable=NO
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
```

The issue is as the one who uploaded the file remains the owner, he's able to delete the file (even though permissions are set to 400).

How would I be able to make so a user can upload and then not being able to remove it through FTP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally been able to find a way to achieve this.
After looking at the manual for the Nth time, I've managed to find the directive `cmds_denied` which disable instructions.

In my case, I've set it to: `cmds_denied=RMD,DELE`.