# FileZilla is uploading files with the wrong owner?

Tags: server, permissions, webserver, sftp, filezilla

For some reason, FileZilla is uploading new files as the user I login as, as opposed to using `www-data:www-data` as it did in the past. This is causing issues because at times, it isn't uploading anything at all.

How do I restore normal behaviour?

UPDATE:
Changing the user back to www-data (see my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147921/1992)) creates an issue where I cannot upload anything, because permission is denied. What could be causing this?

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/935780/vsftpd-change-owner-permissions-once-uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, though not precisely what I'm looking for:

I added my own user to `www-data`, using `sudo usermod -a -G username www-data`, then set permissions to `755` for `/var/www/*`.

Not perfect, but at least it allows things to run smoothly.